# Apache server on centos 8 not serving http pages

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos, httpd

I have a CentOS 8 computer running an httpd server

I was serving both http and https pages properly before

I installed the live chat helper web based chat software using the instructions here: https://devops.ionos.com/tutorials/how-to-install-live-helper-chat-on-centos-7/,
but I deleted it soon after

Now the web server is only serving https pages. Whenever I try to access a page using http, I get a

```
The requested URL /mypage/ was not found on this server.
```

error message.

```
firewall-cmd --list-all
```

shows that I have the following services running:

```
services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ftp htpp https samba ssh telnet
```

My router port forwarding is properly configured and I am sure this is an httpd configuration issue.

How do I find out what is blocking the web server from serving http pages?

Comment: If you are running something like Drupal or Wordpress, you should check the configuration for those. Otherwise, you should check your basic Apache configuration for the site. You may also want to describe in a little deeper detail how you removed this application as well (since those steps may be the source of the issue).

Comment: @Anak i deleted all the files and folders for this app, and deleted it's mariadb user and database